# Retrive data from jquery to pass it into a-frame

Tags: javascript, jquery, aframe, virtual-reality, webvr

how to manipulate data from jquery on a-frame?
my jquery like this

```
$(function() {
    let checkp = JSON.parse('<?= $checkpoint; ?>');
    let base_img = '<?= base_url('assets/vr/images/sphere/hasil/')?>';
    let dump = '';
      for(let i=0; i<checkp.length;i++){
        dump += `<a-cylinder class="clickable" 
                 checkpoint="" 
                 radius="1" 
                 height="0.1" 
                 position="`+checkp[i].checkpoint_position+`" 
                 rotation="`+checkp[i].checkpoint_rotation+`" 
                 scale="`+checkp[i].checkpoint_scale+`" 
                 color="#39BB82" ></a-cylinder>`
            }
      $('#dumpCheckpoint').html(dump);
    });
```

on my console this working fine, but not renddered inside `<a-scane>`

[image]

Comment: Without simple code to run and look at it will be hard to help. Glitch is good for people to provide alternatives: https://glitch.com/edit/#!/aframe

Comment: @DiegoMarcos sory, but can you check this pls? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61807274/aframe-register-componet-add-onclick-attribute