# aframe register componet add onclick attribute

Tags: javascript, jquery, aframe, virtual-reality, webvr

I want to create dynamic componet using aframe
But I cannot add onclick on my component

this my code

```
AFRAME.registerComponent('cylinders', {
init: function(){
let el = this.el;
let sceneEl = document.getElementById('scene1');
let cyl = document.createElement('a-cylinder'); 
    cyl.setAttribute('position', '0 0 0');
    cyl.setAttribute('rotation', '0 0 0');
    cyl.setAttribute('scale', '0 0 0');
    cyl.setAttribute('radius', 1);
    cyl.setAttribute('height', 0.1);
    cyl.setAttribute('color', '#39BB82');
    cyl.setAttribute('checkpoint', '');
    cyl.setAttribute('class', 'clickable');
    cyl.setAttribute('onclick', 'myFunction()');
    sceneEl.appendChild(cyl);
       }           
    }
});
```

my code working fine, but I cannot set onlick. If i write like this bottom I can use onclick.

```
<a-cylinder 
class="clickable" 
checkpoint="" 
radius="1" 
height="0.1" 
position="0 0 0" 
rotation="0 0 0" 
scale="0 0 0" 
onclick="myFunction()"
color="#39BB82">
</a-cylinder>
```

Comment: Without runnable code is hard to help. I recommend https://glitch.com/~aframe to share a minimum example people can look at and suggest solutions

Comment: I had the same problem.
The solution was to add this line to my scene (and onClick started to work):
<a-entity id="mouseCursor" cursor="rayOrigin: mouse"></a-entity>

Answer (score 0):

Read about [a-cursor](https://aframe.io/docs/1.0.0/components/cursor.html#events)

```js
//https://aframe.io/docs/1.0.0/guides/building-a-minecraft-demo.html#try-it-out
```

```html
<script src="https://aframe.io/releases/0.5.0/aframe.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://unpkg.com/aframe-teleport-controls@0.2.x/dist/aframe-teleport-controls.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://unpkg.com/aframe-controller-cursor-component@0.2.x/dist/aframe-controller-cursor-component.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://rawgit.com/ngokevin/kframe/csstricks/scenes/aincraft/components/random-color.js"></script>
<script src="https://rawgit.com/ngokevin/kframe/csstricks/scenes/aincraft/components/snap.js"></script>
<script src="https://rawgit.com/ngokevin/kframe/csstricks/scenes/aincraft/components/intersection-spawn.js"></script>

<body>
  <a-scene>
    <a-assets>
      <img id="groundTexture" src="https://cdn.aframe.io/a-painter/images/floor.jpg">
      <img id="skyTexture" src="https://cdn.aframe.io/a-painter/images/sky.jpg">
      <a-mixin id="voxel"
         geometry="primitive: box; height: 0.5; width: 0.5; depth: 0.5"
         material="shader: standard"
         random-color
         snap="offset: 0.25 0.25 0.25; snap: 0.5 0.5 0.5"
      ></a-mixin>
    </a-assets>

    <a-cylinder id="ground" src="#groundTexture" radius="30" height="0.1"></a-cylinder>

    <a-sky id="background" src="#skyTexture" theta-length="90" radius="30"></a-sky>

    <!-- Hands. -->
    <a-entity id="teleHand" hand-controls="left" teleport-controls="type: parabolic; collisionEntities: [mixin='voxel'], #ground"></a-entity>
    <a-entity id="blockHand" hand-controls="right" controller-cursor intersection-spawn="event: click; mixin: voxel"></a-entity>

    <!-- Camera. -->
    <a-camera>
      <a-cursor intersection-spawn="event: click; mixin: voxel"></a-cursor>
    </a-camera>
  </a-scene>
</body>
```